# Need regular expression that extracts sub-strings that are in some specified format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, string

I have following function that extracts all the sub-strings starting with some character:

```
public static List<string> GetStringsStartingWith(string text, char character)
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!\w)" + character + @"\w+"))
        {
            try
            {
                output.Add(match.Value.Replace(character.ToString(), ""));
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException) { continue; }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

It's working fine for normal strings like `@test`. But now I have some strings that have following format:

> Hello, this is a @[test1].[test2].[test3] string.

Now, what I want is a regular expression that can extract `@[test1].[test2].[test3]` from above string. And there can be a number of formats of such strings. For example, some string might be just `@[test]` or `@[test1].[test2]`.

Above function is unable to extract the string and is returning `null`.

**UPDATE**

I also want to extract those sub-strings that have spaces between `[ ]`. Like this one:

> @[1:contact:Daniel Zahariev]+@[2:contact:Dankajuro].[1:contact:Daniel
>   Zahariev]

Actually these are like user tags that we use on facebook or stackoverflow comments. My system checks the string and when there is a `@` it checks if it is a normal @(for email and others) or representing a tag. This is checked by checking next character after `@` if it is `[` then the information between `[` and `]` is user info. Everything else is just a normal text.

So for above string output should be:

```
@[1:contact:Daniel Zahariev]
@[2:contact:Dankajuro]
```

Comment: How about this ? `@\[.*\]`

Comment: Add rules of what you want to capture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!\w)" + character + @"(\w+\b|\[.*?\](?=[\s+]|$))")
```

To match all non-space characters after `@`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zN9sQ2/3)

Comment: Can you modify it a little so that I can extract from a string like this `@[1:contact:Daniel Zahariev]+@[2:contact:Dankajuro].[1:contact:Daniel Zahariev]`? Actually I want spaces between`[ ]`.

Comment: Actually these are like user tags that we use on facebook or stackoverflow. My system checks the string and when there is a `@` it checks if it is a normal `@`(for email and others) or representing a tag. This is checked by checking next character after `@` if it is `[` then the information between '[' and ']' is user info. Everything else is just a normal text.

Comment: In your demo, it's including `+`. As I said the search should finish for a match when `]` is encountered and then restart search for remaning string. So, your demo should extract 4 matches instead of 3.

Comment: see my question update. I posted the desired output.

Comment: thanks @anubhava. I want to ask one last thing. This is for strictly when there will be a `+`. Can you modify a little so that not only `+` but other characters also should be ignored if came at that place?

Comment: What are those Other characters? Do you have a list of characters?

Comment: Except . and @ followed by [ everything else is allowed at that place.

Comment: You can add more characters in `[\s+]` in above regex to make it something like `[\s+#!%&]` etc

Comment: But that will be a lots of characters. I mean any character that is on the left or right of this sub-string must be ignored. I asked another question related to it. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962718/regular-expression-that-extracts-sub-strings-that-are-in-some-specified-format-n. I explained there more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!\w)" + character + @"\S+"))
                                                                       ↑↑↑
```