# Regular expression that extracts sub-strings that are in some specified format not working for all possibilities

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, string

Continuing from my previous question here: [Need regular expression that extracts sub-strings that are in some specified format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30955540/1124494). The solution that was suggested there solved my problem but not completely. I came across another string sample from which the the sub-strings in following format must be extracted:

> @[any character here].[any character here].[any character here]....... and so on.

For example, I have a string:

> My location is @[XYZ Continent].[XYZ Country].[XYZ State].[XYZ City].[XYZ Street] on the map. You are most welcome there anytime.

Previous solution is working fine on this string. Output:

```
@[XYZ Continent].[XYZ Country].[XYZ State].[XYZ City].[XYZ Street]
```

But that solution only checks for `+` and whitespace outside the sub-string([CLICK HERE TO SEE DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zN9sQ2/3)). But what I want is that the right and left of the sub-string must be ignored no matter if it is alphnumeric, whitespace or another special character. For example:

> Hello@[XYZ Continent1].[XYZ Country1]+@[XYZ Continent2].[XYZ Country2]1@[XYZ Continent3].[XYZ Country3]there.

The output must be:

```
@[XYZ Continent1].[XYZ Country1]
@[XYZ Continent2].[XYZ Country2]
@[XYZ Continent3].[XYZ Country3]
```

Solution from previous question:

```
(?<!\w)@(\w+\b|\[.*?\](?=[\s+]|$))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
(?<!\w)@((?:\[[^\]]+\]\.?)+)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zN9sQ2/4)

Comment: But it's extracting only the string starting with `@` but not those that are in `@[<some text>].[<some text>]` format.

Comment: Are you sure? For your input `Hello@[XYZ Continent1].[XYZ Country1]+@[XYZ Continent2].[XYZ Country2]1@[XYZ Continent3].[XYZ Country3]there` it shows [only one match](https://regex101.com/r/zN9sQ2/7) or I didn't understand the requirement?

Comment: @anubhava In the string there are no spaces.. and because OP already had `(?<!\w)` in his regex i assumed his actual requirement is with `(?<!\w)`

Comment: Yes agreed, but as you can see requirements written in question don't match.

Comment: @anubhava Yes agreed, but as you can see it could be a typo too.. and that requirement can be achieved by removing `(?<!\w)`